# Arduino Mega Shield Library for Eagle CAD

Tags: arduino-mega, shields

I'm a noob to PCB designing and electronic stuff. I want to design a pcb shield which is compatible with an Arduino mega 2560. I'm using Eagle CAD. I checked the sparkfun library but I couldn't find a way to design Mega Shield. Can anybody give me a library or any alternative way to do this?

Comment: You should try Circuit Maker instead.

Comment: Alright Thanks @Jeroen3 I'll give a try. Is it comes with inbuilt libraries for Mega shields?

Comment: Try KiCAD, there are plenty of templates for Arduino, Raspberry, BeagleBone etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you're new user, perhaps it's easier to take an existing project and modify it for your need.
For Eagle, examples can be found on Github.

- https://github.com/zortness/rocket-mega-shield
- https://github.com/practicalarduino/ProtoShieldMega

However, due to recent developments in the PCB EDA world I would suggest you take a look at Circuit Maker. It's more fit for sharing an collaborating designs and libraries. You can easily fork an existing board and use their community parts repository.